# PHP MYSQLI prepared statements login and check the user status

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning to make website with some video tutorials based on mysqli. I came to know that using prepared statements are more secure and I am trying to create a login system. Here is what I have done so far.

This code helps me login success fully.

```
<form action ="" method="post">

User Name:<br/>
<input type='text' name='username' />
<br/><br/>
Password:<br/>
<input type='password' name='password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='login'>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND  password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

              {$_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               echo 'Success!';
               exit();
               }
        }
        else {
            echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else 
    {   

    }
    $con->close();
?>
```

But I also need to check if the user have not activated or have been banned or deactivated. So I made another code.

And here is the code I made

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND    password=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
  {
 $result=$con->query($stmt);
            $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $user_id= $row['user_id'];
            $status = $row['status'];
            if($status=='d'){
                echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo 'Success!';
               exit();
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        
    }
    else 
    {   

    }
 $con->close();
 ?>
```

When I use this I get the following errors

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\login.php on line 33
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\login.php on line 34

I have database table columns

user_id,
username,
password (md5),
user_level,
status.

Under user_level I have the following

```
a = admin
m = member
```

Under status

```
a = activated
n = not activated
d = deactivated
b = banned
```

While logging in I need to check if the user status and if it is activated it should move to index page or if it is d it should show the user has been deactivated and likewise for others.

How to do it in prepared statements?

And I have this connect.php in all page

```
?php
//error_reporting(0);
'session_start';
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if($con->connect_errno > 0){
die('Sorry, We\'re experiencing some connection problems.');
}
?>
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? what is `$result=$con->query($stmt);` for? what does it do there?

Comment: i am new to this i dont know what to do i am stuck

Comment: i want to know am i going in right path

Comment: No, you are going wrong path. For some reason you are selecting absolutely useless login and password but not the activation thing you need

Comment: i saw that for a tutorial using mysql and thought it will help me to check the user status. Am i doing this wrong??? And why is the down vote for???

Comment: How do i do that??? Sir can you give me the changed code as answer please...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are using, but if it works anything like PDO, `$stmt->execute()` is actually running the query. This means that you would want to do something like `$stmt->fetch_array()` to get a row of data rather than try to run the query using the connection object.

Comment: A downvote is for this site is not a school nor a forum of any sort. And "I wrote something I have no idea of, please fix it for me" questions are mere offtopic here.

Comment: I dont have enough money to go to school. So i thought this sight might help. Sorry sir.

Comment: Also, `$row['user_id']` and `$row['status']` will always be empty if you do not add them to the select SQL. `SELECT user_id, username, password, status FROM ...`

Comment: if you want to learn, you have to do it **step by step** instead of trying entire application at once. Learn basic SQL first and then proceed further.

Comment: when i did that it asks for bind param i added it and still not working sir

Comment: i couldn't get enough tutorial based on prepared statements and i get is mysql tutorials. In php.net i couldn't understant properly without guide. @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to take a look into how mysqli_ works. This should get you in the right direction.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $user_id = 0;
    $status = ""

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password, status FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $password, $status);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
               if ($status == 'd') {
                   echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
                   exit();
               } else {
                   $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                   echo 'Success!';
                   exit();
               }
           }

    }
    else {
        echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else 
{   

}
$con->close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You are the first person in the world to help while others just shut the doors on my face when i asked for help. I have tears when i see it works. You will live long sir.

Comment: yes it worked. and you didnt know if it is correct??? Anyways thank you so much sir. This is what i was asking for.

Comment: I knew the logic was correct, I just tend to make little mistakes when writing code on here.