# How can I change my SQL statements to be prepared (and secure) statements?

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, code-injection

Basically I want to protect myself from SQL injections. I have tried searching online and watching videos but cannot understand exactly what I have to change because as far as I can tell, everyone does it a little bit differently. Any help is appreciated!

```
?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("IPAddress","User","Password","DBName");
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Email_Subs (email)
VALUES ('$_POST[email]')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "You have successfully subscribed!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Unless you already ventured too far. Consider reading up on [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Much less overhead for parameterization than the crude mysqli_ API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first use new mysqli() instead of mysqli_connect() to avoid any error in the next php versions

```
    <?php 

    /* CONNECTION */
    $database_connection = new StdClass();

    /** MySQL hostname */
    $database_connection->server = 'localhost';

    /** MySQL database username */
    $database_connection->username = 'root';

    /** MySQL database password */
    $database_connection->password = '';

     /** The name of the database */
     $database_connection->name = 'yourdatabasename';

     /* ESTABLISHING THE CONNECTION */
    $database = new mysqli($database_connection->server, $database_connection->username, $database_connection->password, $database_connection->name); 

            if($database->connect_error) {

                echo 'connection failed';
            }

   ?>
```

Then do smething like this :

```
$stmt = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO Email_Subs (email) VALUES (?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST[email]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$database->close();
```

Comment: Great! That helped a lot, and works perfectly! Is this secure from injections now?

Comment: yeah mate, how about a vote and a check mark for my answer ?

Comment: I checked, but my votes don't count since my reputation is not high enough yet haha. Also, how can I edit this to echo "You have subscribed!" ?

Comment: just add your prepared statement code inside an "isset post" then add the echo before the isset close

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452614/php-mysqli-prepared-statements-login-and-check-the-user-status] this may help you

Comment: This however, doesnt stop any user from spamming my database does it?

Comment: nothing is unbreakable, but for now this is more secured than the normal sql query